# How to leverage the world-size parameter for DistributedDataParallel in Pytorch example for multiple GPUs?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, gpu, pytorch

I am running [this Pytorch example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py) on a `g2.2xlarge` AWS machine. So, when I run `time python imageNet.py ImageNet2`, it runs well with the following timing:

```
real    3m16.253s
user    1m50.376s
sys 1m0.872s
```

However, when I add the `world-size` parameter, it gets stuck and does not execute anything. The command is as follows: `time python imageNet.py --world-size 2 ImageNet2`

So, how do I leverage the `DistributedDataParallel` functionality with the `world-size` parameter in this script. The world-size parameter is nothing but **number of distributed processes**.

Do I spin up another similar instance for this purpose? If yes, then how do the script recognize the instance? Do I need to add some parameters like the instance's IP or something?

Answer (score 0):

World size argument is the number of nodes in your distributed training, so if you set the world size to 2 you need to run the same command with a different rank on the other node. If you just want to increase the number of GPUs on a single node you need to change `ngpus_per_node` instead. Take a look at the multiple node example in this [Readme](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/imagenet).